# What is Adobe ID CC2014 AppBase and can I uninstall it?

Tags: uninstall

I am trying to uninstall Adobe Application Manager or AAM and was told to use Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool. I've run that installer and launched it and I see a program called Adobe ID CC2014 AppBase.

[image]

What is it and can I uninstall it?

**UPDATE:**
Either this software, Adobe Application Manager or something else has completely removed InDesign CC from my computer. I could be wrong but I have no memory of uninstalling it at all. FYI I worked as contractor and required InDesign for work (was provided a legitimate  distributed license). I finished that contract a month ago. I don't use InDesign but checking just now and the software is no where on my system.

Comment: It's part of InDesign CC (2014). If you aren't using InDesign you can uninstall it.

Comment: WTH? It also appears to have uninstalled it?

Comment: Did you previously uninstall InDesign? Maybe Appbase was a leftover?

Comment: No. I've updated the details above.